# Jmeter cannot find keytool application and no keystore was provided. Tried alll

Tags: performance, testing, automation, jmeter

Im working with Jmeter, trying to running it as a proxy, but when I start recording, I got this alert. I tried setting user.properties, but i can’t find a solution. Please, so grateful if you help me!

[image: alert jmeter]

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to be able to record [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) traffic JMeter generates special [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) certificate which needs to be installed in the browser
2. In order to be able to generate the certificate JMeter needs [`keytool`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/keytool.html) command which normally lives in "bin" folder of JDK or JRE

So make sure to add the "bin" folder of your Java installation to your operating system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) and it should resolve your issue.

- Example command on Windows:

  ```
  setx PATH=c:\java\bin;%PATH% && jmeter.bat
  ```
- Example command on Unix and derivatives:

  ```
  PATH=/opt/java/bin:$PATH && ./jmeter.sh
  ```

Replace `c:\java` or `/opt/java` with the real path to your JDK or JRE installation.

You should get something like:

[image]

if you launch JMeter from the same terminal window you will be able to start the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder without any issues

Also be aware that there is an easier way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and SSL certificates

Answer (score 0):

I have JMeter 5.5 and Java JDK 20 installed. System path is set properly. keytool can be run in CMD as shown in the screenshot below. But I still run into the exact same error as shown in the question. I even added the path for the keytool.dirtory in JMeter System Properties. But still no luck :-(

Comment: This is not an answer.